# Prove or Disprove: $a \equiv b \bmod m$ iff $a^3 \equiv b^3 \bmod m$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Prove or Disprove: $a \equiv b \mod m$ iff $a^3 \equiv b^3 \mod m$?

I'm trying to determine if this is true or not. I have already proved this going one way. I know that if $a \equiv b \mod m$ then $a^3 \equiv b^3 \mod m$.

How should I start the second direction?
I know that I'm starting with $mk=b^3-a^3$ and I need to get down to $mj=b-a$ for some $k,j \in \mathbb{Z}$. Any hints on how to get there?

Comment: Consider $\,m = a^3 - b^3\ \ $

Comment: Look for a counter example. There might be one when $m=4$.

Comment: $0,2,4,6\mod 8$

Comment: @Pawel That's essentially special case $\,a,b = 0,2\,$ in my initial comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to find lots of counterexamples.  Take positive integers $b > a$ and look for numbers $m$ that divide $b^3 - a^3$ but don't divide $b-a$.

Comment: For the record: this hint was already given $30$ minutes prior in the first commen on the question.